# Getting:"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'", only when running from the command line

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run the Transformer (speech2text) model on windows (till I get my linux machine).
when I'm running the entire command from the cmd:

"python transformer_main.py --data_dir=$DATA_DIR --model_dir=$MODEL_DIR --params=$PARAMS"

I'm getting an error :"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'"

But I know that tf is installed and also when I'm using pycharm, first, I can see the package installed(File -> Settings ->Project interpreter).
second, when I'm running the code it's passing that fall site...

I can run through pycharm, but I think it's important to understand what I'm missing, Is it something with the interpreter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are simply using a different interpreter from your command line than from your PyCharm project. This will happen, for example, if you have set up your PyCharm project using a fresh conda environment.

To see which one you are using on the command-line, simply run `where python`. Then compare this with what you found in PyCharm.

Comment: Thanks a lot, acctually im not using conda (gave me some problems) , but I got this output:
C:\Users\bbattach\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\bbattach\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe".

How can I change to the second interpeter?

Comment: In this case, the first one of the two is the one that will be called when you run `python`. That is, running your module from the command line will use the interpreter at `C:\Users\bbattach\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe`, which is likely not the same as the PyCharm project is set up to use.